# 7-Segment display with printf and multidimensional array for segments

Tags: c, ascii-art

In K.N Kings "C programming: A modern approach", chapter 10 exercise 7, the task is to make a digit converter from normal digits to 7-segment digits in ASCII art, like this:

```
   _   _        _   _   _   _   _   _ 
|  _|  _|  |_| |_  |_    | |_| |_| | |
| |_   _|    |  _| |_|   | |_|   | |_|
```

---

I got the sequence for each digit where to turn in it on and off

sample:

```
int digit_sequence[10][7] = {
    // A,B,C,D,E,F,G
    /* 0 */ {1,1,1,1,1,1,0}

}
```

Where 1 = ON, 0 = OFF

but I have a hard time getting the `process_digit(int digit, int position)` function to work.

I have a hard time in my head translating from `sequence[10][7]` to `digits[4][MAX_DIGITS*4]`

Could a kind soul please help me?

I have been reading the golf code seven-segment challenge, but even though I understand that theory it's still hard to convince my brain into doing what I want with multiple arrays.

---

Ignoring the ASCII art, the question reads:

> Write a program that prompts the user for a number and then displays the number using characters to simulate the effect of a seven-segment display.
>
> ...
>
> Characters other than digits should be ignored. Write the program so that the maximum number of digits is controlled by a macro named MAX_DIGITS which has the value 10.  If the number contains more than this number of digits, the extra digits are ignored.  *Hints:* Use two external arrays.  One is the `segments` array [...] which stores data representing the correspondence between digits and segments.  The other array, `digits`, will be an array of characters with 4 rows (since each segmented digit is 4 characters high) and `MAX_DIGITS * 4` columns (digits are three characters wide but a spaces is needed between digits for readability).  Write your program as four functions: `main`, [...]
>
> ```
> void clear_digits_array(void);
> void process_figit(int digit, int position);
> void print_digits_array(void);
> ```
>
> `clear_digits_array` will store blank characters into all elements of the digits array. `process_digit` will store the seven-segment representation of `digit` into a specified position in the `digits` array (positions range from `0` to `MAX_DIGITS - 1`). `print_digits_array` will display the rows of the digits array, each on a single line [...].

Comment: You should explain this a bit better, what are the purposes of `digit_sequence[]` and `digits[]`? What's the intent of the `process_digit()` function you mention?

Comment: You are making the classic beginner's mistake of assuming we know what you are trying to do. We have never heard of the `process_digit` function and don't know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Chapter 10 comes just before 'Chapter 11: Pointers' and 'Chapter 12: Pointers and Arrays' in the book.

Comment: We had a *battle royale* with these programs in comp.lang.c a few years ago. [This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/browse_thread/thread/2f4d61a175e3eaad/defb23aba8c0f0e5?lnk=gst&q=seven+segment+display) has a lot of info (and non-golfed programs).

Comment: To all, thanks for replying, and yes I overdid the question, but I was far in my thoughts when trying to write the question and at the same time trying to figure out the problem.
(AT)JonathanLeffler I woudld like to complete the excersize before knowing about pointers and arrays, as it should be solvable without taking the step towards pointers, and from the books perspective at that stage I wouldnt know anything of pointers.
(AT)luserdroog I would sincerely thank you for the best answer to this question as you pointed me forward to another thread I had trouble locating with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to map where a segment goes on display.

The line number is the same for each segment.

```
0:  _   _
1: |_| |_| ...
2: |_| |_|
3:
```

However, the columns vary by `position`. Each position is a 4 characters width 'mini-matrix' (3 for segments and 1 for space: `'|_| '`). So we fix the line of segment and sum its column on the 'mini-matrix' with (position*4).

```
0123 4567 89AB
 _    _    _
|_|  |_|  |_|   ...
|_|  |_|  |_|
pos0 pos1 pos2
```

Got it? The code will be something like that:

```
void process_digit(int digit, int position){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(segments[digit][i]==1) /* Has digit the i segment? */
            switch(i){
                case 0: digits[0][1+position*4]='_';break;
                case 1: digits[1][2+position*4]='|';break;
                case 2: digits[2][2+position*4]='|';break;
                case 3: digits[2][1+position*4]='_';break;
                case 4: digits[2][0+position*4]='|';break;
                case 5: digits[1][0+position*4]='|';break;
                case 6: digits[1][1+position*4]='_';break;
            }
    }
}
```

(You may choose between '-' and '_', or perhaps change some lines)

Hope it helps.